# String to Hex stored in an int

Tags: c#, string, int

I currently have this code

```
int MainBase = 0x4E4DBC;
```

I dont want it hard coded so I decided to setup a config file. so I have a string with "4E4DBC".

How would I parse it so it can be in the int? Ive already tried Byte.Parse and Convert.ToByte but they both give me "Too Large" errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[First hit on google](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397679.aspx):

```
Convert.ToInt32("4E4DBC", 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx) method:

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32("4E4DBC", 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

Never store memory locations in an integer, use `IntPtr`, it's there for a reason. Reason being is that `IntPtr` works on both x86 and x64, whereas an `int` is too small for storing a 64bit pointer (which is a `long`), so you'll run into problems when you switch platforms.

Use the answers above to parse it into an `int`, then use something along the lines of

`var somePtr = new IntPtr(value);`

And your pointers will be 4 bytes if on x86, and 8 bytes on x64, respectively.

Also, a `byte` is only one byte, and therefore will never be able to store an integer, which is 4 bytes. That's why you got the "Too Large" errors in VS. You can find information on [how large the types in C# are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx). You should look it up.